# copy content from command prompt through command line

Tags: ghostscript

I'm using [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to get the resolution for a `PDF` file. When I pass this command:

```
gswin32c.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=bbox D:\sample.pdf
```

I get this result:

```
%%BoundingBox: 67 59 772 1070
%%HiResBoundingBox: 67.918568 59.278569 771.475406 1069.373006
```

I need to copy the result `%%BoundingBox: 67 59 772 1070` to a text or `XML` file using the command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a Ghostscript question. Use the command shell redirection operators to send the output from stderr and stdout to files (you want > out.txt).

Comment: My bad... I did a little search, bbox device writes to the stderr (2) and I try stdout (1) so the complete command looks like: gswin32c.exe -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=bbox test.pdf 2>test.txt